# I want to create a BQ table if Dag is fail or success

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

if DAG is failure or success I want that information in my BigQuery Table

I have a Airflow DAG on GCP composer that runs every 5 minutes. I would like to create a BigQuery table that will have the time when DAG starts to run and a flag identifying whether it's a successful run or failed run. For example, if the DAG runs at 2020-03-23 02:30 and the run fails, the BigQuery table will have time column with 2020-03-23 02:30 and flag column with 1. If it's a successful run, then the table will have time column with 2020-03-23 02:30 and flag column with 0. The table will append new rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a on_success_callback and a on_failure_callback on your DAG.
You should create a (python) function that logs information from the [airflow.models.taskinstance](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/taskinstance/index.html#module-airflow.models.taskinstance)

```py
dag.on_success_callback = log_dag_run_status_to_bigquery
dag.on_failure_callback = log_dag_run_status_to_bigquery
```

In the python function you can do the following thing:

```py
def log_dag_run_status_to_bigquery(ti: TaskInstance):
  # Extract relevant information from the task instance
  dag_id = ti.dag_id
  execution_date = ti.execution_date
  start_time = ti.start_date
  end_time = ti.end_date
  success = ti.state == 'success'  # Determine if the task succeeded or failed

  # Create a BigQuery row with the required information
  row = {
    'time': execution_date,
    'flag': int(success),
    'dag_id': dag_id,
    'start_time': start_time,
    'end_time': end_time
  }

  # stream row to bigquery by using bigqueryClient
```